# Including files relative to project directory in c++

Tags: c++, include

I have some header files contained in sub directories of the project source. Having to do `#include "../../Foo.h"` inside these files looks kinda messy in my opinion, when I'd much prefer to do `#include "dir1/dir2/Foo.h"` for faster human reading and understanding - is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously you can.  (And should)

Tell the compiler to add "projectdir/../.." to its include path.  On Microsoft this would be using the `/I` switch, on gcc it's `-I`.

---- edit -----

In Visual Studio, you can use ['Macros'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).  In this case `$(ProjectDir)/../..` should do.

Better still, if you can organize it that way:  create a solution in the 'root' dir, add projects in subdirs, and use `$(SolutionDir)/projectX/includes` on your C++ include path.

Even more better still: add the dependent project as a [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) to your project.  VS should automatically add its directory and lib to the compiler and linker settings.

Comment: Excellent, in visual studio, is there a boolean flag somewhere to include the project dir , or do I need to add the /I?

Comment: Maybe it's messy, but I just added $(ProjectDir) to the includes directories in the project properties